# Capitalize after point and space only the next word after point ( maybe regex + ucfirst )

Tags: regex, str-replace, ucfirst

Capitalize after point and space only the next word after point, maybe using regex + ucfirst..

```
preg_match('/[\s\.][a-z]/'
$theCode = str_replace(ucfirst.....
```

In summary is to do uppercase only in the first letter after spaço + point, in all data of the variable.

```
$theCode = 'babab. babab babab. bababa bababa bababa. bababa babab baba';
```

out:

```
$theCode = 'babab. Babab babab. Bababa bababa bababa. Bababa babab baba';
```

No matter what method I adopted, I just suggested.

Thanks

Comment: maybe you should add tag with php? or you don't care about language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For php, `preg_replace_callback` + `ucfirst`

[live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e15da08d2d1e080bacec034d6eae0005e30f3df4)

```
$theCode = 'babab. babab babab. bababa bababa bababa. bababa babab baba';
$pattern = '/([a-z][^.]*)/i';

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) {
    return ucfirst($matches[0]);
}, $theCode);

echo $result;
```

For javascript,

```js
function capitalizeAll(str) {
   return str.replace(/([a-z])([^.]*)/gi, (a, b, c) => {
      return (b || '').toUpperCase() + c;
   });
}

var theCode = 'babab. babab babab. bababa bababa bababa. bababa babab baba';

console.log(capitalizeAll(theCode));
```

Comment: There is no need in capture group. You're using `$matches[0]` only so `/[a-z][^.]*/i` would [do perfectly well](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/497ffd7244215c51768209ef772864564965f383).

Comment: @DmitryEgorov what's your suggestion to make php code better? =)

Comment: The PHP code is fine and pretty much matches to what I was going to post but you won the race:)

Comment: If any non-Latin characters may be found at the beginning of a sentence, you may need to replace `[a-z]` with [`\p{L}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). `ucfirst` would also fail in the case. `mb_strtoupper` would have to be used instead: [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6b789685e65ae7d0f2a14fb81bb7be630bba545a)

Comment: @DmitryEgorov it's ok we're both just trying to be helpful. 40 minutes faster can't tell a fair race though

Comment: @DmitryEgorov Thank you! I know nothing about Spainish capitalization..

Comment: In the JavaScript snippet the conditional operator may be omitted since `/([a-z][^.]*)/` always returns a match which is at least one character long. You may also have a somewhat shorter substitution function if break the sentence into the first letter and the rest: [`str.replace(/([a-z])([^.]*)/gi, (a, b, c) => { return b.toUpperCase()+c })`](https://jsfiddle.net/cg4pwvup/)

Comment: You're right, this one looks more elegant. can I use this, or maybe you could have another answer with Latin language capitalize?

Comment: Great @Val It was PHP, sorry I was absent, and I really forgot to say the language! Thank you. It worked very well.